# Удаление предыдущих сообщений в телеграм-боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мне нужно, чтобы телеграм бот удалял свои предыдущее сообщения. Я попробовал сделать, но учитель сказал, что в моём коде 2 ошибки, помогите, пожалуйста, найти и исправить.
Вот мой код:

```py
def get_kb(*btns: dict[str]):
    markups = []
    i = 0
    kb = []
    for x in btns:
        i += 1
        if i % 3 == 0:
            markups.append(kb)
            kb = []
        kb.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=x.get('text'),
                  callback_data=x.get('call'), url=x.get('url')))
    else:
        markups.append(kb)
    return types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(markups)
```

Comment: кто то мне поможет?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что у вас е работает и как должно работать?

Comment: если 2 человека одновременно пользуются ботом то в коде выходит ошибка мне надо чтоб сколько угодно человек пользовались ботом и все работало, учитель сказал что там 2 ошибки.

Comment: Тот код который вы скинули никак не связан с количеством пользователей бота, а даже с самим вопросом